# force and fraud are in war the two cardinal virtues

Tags: comprehension

This is a quote from Thomas Hobbes:

> Force and fraud are in war the two cardinal virtues.

To me, ***force and fraud are in war*** and ***the two cardinal virtues*** sound like two totally independent statements. If there were a long dash that separated them, I'd probably understand the sentence perfectly well. But there's none. So, how do you think one should understand that sentence grammatically?

Comment: Are you certain there aren't commas around "in war"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer

> The original sentence means: **In war, the two cardinal virtues are force and fraud.**

#### Analysis

- **virtues** = **force and fraud**.
- **in war** *qualifies* when the equation applies.
- **two** *modifies* **virtues** by telling us *how many* virtues the writer is describing.
- **cardinal** *modifies* **virtues**.